# Can't delete an iptables chain

Tags: firewall, iptables

I'm having a problem on deleting a user-defined chain.
these the are rules I entered.

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -N internet
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j internet
sudo iptables -t mangle -A internet -j MARK --set-mark 99
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m mark --mark 99 -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.3.1
```

When i'm using -X or -D, it gives me this error

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

EDIT:
this is the command i used to delete the "internet" chain

```
iptables -F internet
```

i also tried using this:

```
iptables -D internet
```

and

```
iptables -X internet
```

but it still gives me the same message.

Comment: Sorry about that. i already edited my post

Comment: Could you provide the command you use when attempting the delete?

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it still gives me the same error. I want to reconfigure my iptables and i need to delete those 4 commands I entered first.

Answer (score 3):

To flush ALL your rules use:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -X
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -X
```